# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'checkClientAccess' expects parameter '@AccessCode', which was not supplied.'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, xmlhttprequest

I've read up on other posts that are similar and an error that people make is that the value that is being passed to the stored procedure is null. In my code I have multiple console.log to indicate that the value is there and that it is not null. I believe there is an error with my xml request post object because that's how it gets sent to the API which is then where the stored procedure is called along with the given parameter. I'm not too sure where the error is, but the title of the post is what comes up in the API code.

**JavaScript Function (containing XML REQUEST)**

```
function checkClientAccess()
{
    var accessCode = document.getElementById('accessCodeInput').value;
    console.log(accessCode); //test to see if value is in storage variable
    
    if(accessCode=='')
    {
        alert("Please enter your access code")
        return false;
    }
    
    var postObj = {
        inputCode: accessCode
    };
    
    console.log(postObj); //test to see if value is in post Object
    
    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    console.log("New Request"); //test to see if new xmlRequest object is created
    
    xmlRequest.open('POST','https://localhost:44303/api/JSON/checkClientAccess',true);
    
    console.log("Open post request at specified URL")//test to see if new post request opened 
    
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    console.log("Request header set") //test to see if request header is set 
    
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        
        console.log("XML request onreadystatexchange function started"); //test to see if function started 
        
        if(this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200)
        {
            
            console.log("Request complete and done"); //test to see if request is complete or has responded done
            
            if(xmlRequest.response=="-1")
            {
                alert("Never make the same mistake twice, you have entered an invalid code");
            }
            if(xmlRequest.response=="1")
            {
                location.href = 'login-page.html?action=valid';
            }
            
        }
    }
    
        console.log(postObj) //test to see if value is still in post object
        
        xmlRequest.send(JSON.stringify(postObj));
        
        console.log("Xml request post object sent") // test to see if post object has been sent, or at least has passed this line of code
        
        
        return false;
}
```

**API Code (ASP.NET MVC)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FelixFringsPharmacopeiaAPI.Models;

namespace FelixFringsPharmacopeiaAPI.Controllers
{

    public class JSONController : ApiController
    {

        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public object checkClientAccess(Models.clientAccess client)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            string sql = "checkClientAccess";
            var json = ExecuteSPcheckClientAccess(sql, client.accessCode);

            response.Content = new StringContent(json);
            return response;
        }

        
        

        private static string ExecuteSPcheckClientAccess(string queryString, string inputCode)
        {
            string json = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconn"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccessCode", inputCode));
              

                // execute the command
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // iterate through results, printing each to console
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        json = (string)rdr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL Server Database Stored Procedure Code**

```
USE [FelixFringsPharmacopeia]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[checkClientAccess]    Script Date: 8/26/2021 5:06:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkClientAccess] 
    
    @AccessCode varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

if 1 = (select count(*) from AccessCodes where ActiveAccessCode = @AccessCode)
begin
    select 1; --indicates that user input matches access code, is valid
    return;
end

select -1; --indicated that user input does not match access code, is not valid
return;

END
```

**JavaScript Console Log**

```
123456 - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:16 
{inputCode: "123456"} - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:20 
New Request - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:24 
Open post request at specified URL - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:28 
Request header set - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:51 
{inputCode: "123456"} - FelixFringsPharmacopeiaApplicationFunctions.js:55 
Xml request post object sent
```

Comment: Is it `accessCode` or `inputCode`? The name seems to change at different layers of your software stack.

Comment: The post obj sets 'inputCode' to the value of accessCode that was defined right above.

Comment: Try this one:
var postObj = {"client": {"accessCode": accessCode}};

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Actually you are right, in the mvc api, the model variable name has to match the name thats coming in. You helped me find the error, thankyou very much, this literally took hours to do

Comment: Side note: you can simplify the stored procedure to `select case when exists (select 1 from AccessCodes where ActiveAccessCode = @AccessCode) then 1 else -1 end`. And since you only have a single value, you don't need a `DataReader`, just use `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccessCode", SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = inputCode;
```